# boto3, Where is credential file on Windows?

Tags: boto3

boto3 looks for the credentials in

```
~/.aws/credentials
```

But where is that on Windows?

I see that I can change the location by changing AWS_CONFIG_FILE, but that's in ~/.aws/config, so same question.

This, by the way, is the code I'm tring to run (Python):

```
import boto3
credentials = boto3.Session().get_credentials()
```

Comment: In Windows  C:\Users\<UserName>\.aws\credentials.

Comment: Let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: for more info: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In windows:   `C:\Users\<UserName>\.aws\credentials`

Comment: Worked perfectly.